# update document with greatest/lowest value

Tags: mongodb

I want to update a document with the latest timestamp.
My first thought was, to do it with a sort, but this is currently not supported:

```
db.collection("items").update({
    ids: { $in: searchIds }
}, {
    $set: {
        timestamp: currentTimestamp
    }
}, {
    sort: {
        timestamp: -1
    }
});
```

Is there a way to update a document which have the greatest/lowest value with one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) which provides more flexibility than `update`.  In the shell:

```js
db.items.findAndModify({
    query: { ids: { $in: searchIds }},
    sort: { timestamp: -1 },
    update: { $set: { timestamp: currentTimestamp }}
});
```